# delete multiple items in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, delete-file

I am trying to delete multiple items in android but the problem is that when I select multiple items and press delete the dialog box does not disappear and you have to press delete as much times as the items you want to delete which is not the right behavior.

```
for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
    String delete_id = v.getId();
    long long_id = Long.parseLong(delete_id);
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,long_id);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setCancelable(true)
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    activity.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    files.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, files.size());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("no",null);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
            .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
    alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
}
```

This is the Adapter class in which the this is implemented

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
   public MyAdapter(Activity activity,List<ItemFiles> files) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.files= files;
     }

 public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
            position) {

holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                switch (id) {
                   case R.id.delete:
                    for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
          String delete_id = v.getId();
          long long_id = Long.parseLong(delete_id);
          Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,long_id);
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
          builder.setCancelable(true)
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    activity.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                    files.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, files.size());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("no",null);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
               .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
        alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
              .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
}
```

how do I delete mutiple selected items which is "v" in this case on single click and make the dialog box disappear ? Thanks.

Comment: Are your using the RecycleView? Do you hope the Dialog show only once?

Comment: I am using recylerview and yes I want the dialog to show once

Answer (score 1):

could try to move the dialog out of the for-loop, and remove the selectList files :

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return files.size();
    }

    void deleteMultiItems(List<ItemFiles> selectList, Activity activity, int position, List<ItemFiles> files) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setCancelable(true)
                .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
                            String delete_id = v.getId();
                            long long_id = Long.parseLong(delete_id);
                            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, long_id);
                            activity.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                        }
                        files.removeAll(selectList);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("no", null);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
                .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
        alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black));
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int
            position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                          deleteMultiItems(selectList,activity,position,files);
            }
        }
    }
```

you may need to override the equal() of ItemFile.class

```
class ItemFiles {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        ItemFiles itemFiles =(ItemFiles)obj;
        return this.id.equals(itemFiles.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is not deleting anything the dialog disappears as expected on a click.

Comment: Did you success to delete one item? Could show more code  about  the adapter and where use the code.@MBaig

Comment: I tried this and it works in deleting one item  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                                    for (ItemFiles v : selectList) { // the rest of the code